# Is the product of two analytic function is analytic then one is constant and other is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

show that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic function on a region $G$ such that $fg$ is analytic then either $f$ is constant or $g \equiv 0$

Comment: That's not true as stated. The product of two analytic functions is always analytic.

Comment: $\sin(2z)$ is analytic. $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ both are analytic /

Comment: this ques is also confused me, but i get this question in the book "Jhon B conway", chapter-complex integration, i am confused question is wright or wrong.

Comment: Probably the intention was to have you show that if $f,g$ are analytic, and $f\cdot g \equiv 0$, then $f \equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: @MSMM, in what page/section **exactly** in that chapter of Conwat's book?

Comment: I already found the question in the book and, of course, it is different of what the OP wrote: here we're missing the "slightly important" (!) condition that $\;f(z)g(z)=0\;,\;z\in G\;$ ...!

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=z^2$, both are analytic (in fact entire), the product is again analytic. So, the statement is not true .